# Why Ajax is sending empty data

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am sending data in ajax it sending empty but in console it is showing array.
I want to transfer the data in post to store in database I am sending data in ajax it sending empty but in console it is showing array.
I want to transfer the data in post to store in database I am sending data in ajax it sending empty but in console it is showing array.
I want to transfer the data in post to store in database

```js
  $('#checking').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var myCheckboxes = [];
    var test = [];
    var checker = [];

    $.each($("input[name='mycheck']:checked"), function() {
      myCheckboxes.push($(this).val());
      var check = $(this).attr('id');
      var start = $('#start' + check).val();
      var startid = $('#start' + check).attr('id');
      var end = $('#end' + check).val();
      test[startid] = start + ',' + end;
    });

    checker.push(test);
    var ss = new Array(checker);
    console.log(checker);

    $.ajax({
      url: "data.php",
      type: 'GET',
      data: "Data=" + ss,
      success: function(data) {
        if (data != 1) {
          alert('Done');
        } else {
          alert("Not Ok");
        }
      }
    });
  });
});
    <form  id="checking" method="POST" >
        <?php

    $checkbox='';
    $weeknames=array(1=>'Monday',2=>'Tuesday',3=>'Wednesday',4=>'Thursday',5=>'Friday',6=>'Saturday',7=>'Sunday');
    foreach($weeknames as $key=>$value)
    {
        $checkbox.='<br/><input type="checkbox" id='.$key.'  name="mycheck" value='.$value.' />'.$value.'&nbsp Start<input type="time"  id=start'.$key.' />End<input type="time" name="timing" id=end'.$key.'  />';
    }    
print_r($checkbox).'<br/>';
?>
        <button  id="sub"  name="btnregister">Submit</button>      
        </form>
```

Comment: If you want to post data to the server, you should use POST request. type: 'POST'.

Comment: i tried but in both it desnt work

Comment: Could you please share the HTML as well?

Comment: <form  id="checking" method="POST" >
        <?php
       
    $checkbox='';
    $weeknames=array(1=>'Monday',2=>'Tuesday',3=>'Wednesday',4=>'Thursday',5=>'Friday',6=>'Saturday',7=>'Sunday');
    foreach($weeknames as $key=>$value)
    {
        $checkbox.='<br/><input type="checkbox" id='.$key.'  name="mycheck" value='.$value.' />'.$value.'&nbsp Start<input type="time"  id=start'.$key.' />End<input type="time" name="timing" id=end'.$key.'  />';
    }    
echo $checkbox.'<br/>';
?>
        <button  id="sub"  name="btnregister">Submit</button>      
        </form>

Comment: If the data is showing in the console then the JS side appears fine. How are you handling the request in `data.php`?

Comment: print_r($_POST);

Comment: This might show the content of `test` but I guess that `test.length` is still zero

Comment: when i am writing in data: checker[0]['start7'] it sending its value ,how

Comment: Can you edit your post and provide it with the html and data.php ..

Comment: i have edited the post

Comment: @Raj can you also put the contents of data.php?